# How could we detect strings which are made of subpattern‽

Tags: java, string, algorithm, unit-testing, substring

I am doing the following programming exercise: [String subpattern recognition I](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5a49f074b3bfa89b4c00002b). The statement is:

> In this kata you need to build a function to return either true/True
>   or false/False if a string can be seen as the repetition of a
>   simpler/shorter subpattern or not.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> hasSubpattern("a") === false; //no repeated pattern
> hasSubpattern("aaaa") === true; //created repeating "a"
> hasSubpattern("abcd") === false; //no repeated pattern
> hasSubpattern("abababab") === true; //created repeating "ab"
> hasSubpattern("ababababa") === false; //cannot be entirely reproduced
> repeating a pattern
> ```
>
> Strings will never be empty and can be composed of any character (just
>   consider upper- and lowercase letters as different entities) and can
>   be pretty long (keep an eye on performances!).

I have written the following answer:

```
public class Kata {
  public static boolean hasSubpattern(String str) {
    if(str.length() <= 1) return false;
    String pattern = "";
    for(int i = 0; i <= str.length()/2; i++){
      String letter = String.valueOf(str.charAt(i));
      pattern += letter;
      String repeated = pattern.repeat(str.length()/pattern.length());
      if(repeated.equals(str)){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Being 4 traces the followings:

```
str: a

str: aaaa
letter: a
pattern: a
repeated: aaaa

str: abcd
letter: a
pattern: a
repeated: aaaa
letter: b
pattern: ab
repeated: abab
letter: c
pattern: abc
repeated: abc

str: abababab
letter: a
pattern: a
repeated: aaaaaaaa
letter: b
pattern: ab
repeated: abababab
```

So then, the code passes the normal tests (with small length strings). However it does not pass with bigger strings, because it times out (the execution time is more than 1600ms).

I tried other approach, instead of repeating each pattern, we are now replacing it all from the original string.

```
public class Kata {
  public static boolean hasSubpattern(String str) {
    if(str.length() <= 1) return false;
    String pattern = "";
    for(int i = 0; i <= str.length()/2; i++){
      String letter = String.valueOf(str.charAt(i));
      pattern += letter;
      String repeated = str.replaceAll(pattern,"");
      if(repeated.equals("")){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

However it stills timing out with bigger strings.

After that I tried again using this code:

```
public class Kata {
  public static boolean hasSubpattern(String str) {
    if(str.length() <= 1) return false;
    String pattern = "";
    for(int i = 0; i <= str.length()/2; i++){
      String letter = String.valueOf(str.charAt(i));
      pattern += letter;   
      String regex = "("+pattern+"){"+str.length()/pattern.length()+"}";
      if(str.matches(regex)){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

However it keeps timing out. I suppose we need to remove the foor loop.

Besides I have read:

- [Java String Pattern Recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664861/java-string-pattern-recognition)
- [What's the difference between Matcher.lookingAt() and find()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008397/whats-the-difference-between-matcher-lookingat-and-find)
- [Is there a regular expression to detect a valid regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression?rq=1)

In addition while reading similar topics on Stack Overflow, I found one which describes this kata's Python solution. Here is the link:

- [String subpattern recognition optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507418/string-subpattern-recognition-optimization)

So then we could just use the following code:

```
public class Kata {
  public static boolean hasSubpattern(String str) {
    return str.matches("^(\\w+)\\1+$");
  }
}
```

Which made me learnt that we can mention to a previous matched group inside the regex itselft, by writting an escaped number related to what group we are looking for. In this case \1 refers to (\w+)

However I would like to discuss how could we achieve one iterative solution which works for bigger inputs.

How could we detect strings which are made of subpattern‽

Comment: If your problem is performance, your first step should be to benchmark it. You are trying to optimize based on assumptions. Be empirical. Write a proper test, identify the bottlenecks and work out how you can overcome them.

Comment: FWIW, *my* assumption would be that regular expressions are too heavyweight for this problem and that you will be able to achieve much better performance with more primitive constructs (e.g. `char[]`). But don't take my word for it. Profile it and see.